# git reset --hard HEAD Vs. git reset --hard

Tags: git

What is the difference between `git reset --hard HEAD` and `git reset --hard`? I think both do exactly the same and are simply synonyms, but please let me know if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: It defaults to `HEAD` if a tree/commit is not provided. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#_description

Comment: @JeffMercado In other words, yes, `git reset --hard HEAD`=`git reset --hard`. Of course, when I say `git reset --hard` I mean that after that the Enter key is pressed (no tree/commit provided).

Answer (score 2):

[`git reset` man page is clear](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):

> The `<tree-ish>/<commit>` defaults to HEAD in all forms.

That is from [git v1.7.2.3, commit 7b8cd49, July 2010](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b8cd49d5cc5aeb3723be616993bfc7fc847c34f)

Answer (score 1):

When want to revert to a previous commit then use:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

If need to reset all mess created during revert use:

```
$git reset --hard <commit-id>
```

Comment: By "to a previous commit", do you mean "to the latest previous commit"?

Comment: When I want to revert to a previous commit, then both `git reset --hard HEAD` and `git reset --hard` are synonyms, they do exactly the same, correct? That is my question.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question comparing `git reset --hard` with and without `HEAD`. This answer only gives two examples of `git reset`.